# Google Plus DomainsAPI wide-domain autorization

Tags: google-app-engine, google-plus

Good morning I'm trying to integrate the `Google+ Domains` API with my company domain but I'm facing some problems.

I'm trying the java approach following the quick start for java but after implement the code the response from the google server is :

```
Authenticate the domain for hugo.catarino@outsystems.com
Inserting activity
10/Set/2013 17:08:49 com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClient <init>
WARNING: Application name is not set. Call Builder#setApplicationName.
Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException:400 Bad Request
{
   "error" : "access_denied"
}
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException.from(TokenResponseException.java:105)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:287)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.execute(TokenRequest.java:307)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.executeRefreshToken(GoogleCredential.java:269)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.refreshToken(Credential.java:489)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.intercept(Credential.java:217)
at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:858)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:410)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
at com.google.plus.samples.quickstart.domains.DomainDelegation.main(DomainDelegation.java:160)
```

here is used authentication method and my variables:

```
private static final String SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = "638852846577@developer.gserviceaccount.com";

private static final String SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH =
  "src/com/google/plus/samples/quickstart/domains/05cab8e819cbd0a747b180c1f22fc93dba916b7b-privatekey.p12";

private static final String USER_EMAIL = "hugo.catarino@outsystems.com";




private static Plus authenticate() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {

System.out.println(String.format("Authenticate the domain for %s", USER_EMAIL));

HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

// Setting the sub field with USER_EMAIL allows you to make API calls using the special keyword
// 'me' in place of a user id for that user.
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
    .setTransport(httpTransport)
    .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
    .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
    .setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPE)
    .setServiceAccountUser(USER_EMAIL)
    .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(
        new java.io.File(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH)).build();

// Create and return the Plus service object
Plus service = new Plus.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential).build();

return service;
}
```

My main class has the following code like in the sample:

```
Plus service = authenticate();

String userId = "me";
String msg = "Happy Monday! #caseofthemondays";

System.out.println("Inserting activity");

// Create the audience of the post
PlusAclentryResource res = new PlusAclentryResource();
// Share to the domain
res.setType("domain");

List<PlusAclentryResource> aclEntries = new ArrayList<PlusAclentryResource>();
aclEntries.add(res);

Acl acl = new Acl();
acl.setItems(aclEntries);
// Required, this does the domain restriction
acl.setDomainRestricted(true);

Activity activity = new Activity()
    .setObject(new Activity.PlusObject().setOriginalContent(msg))
    .setAccess(acl);

activity = service.activities().insert(userId, activity).execute();

System.out.println(activity);
```

In domain `cPanel` the company defined for me the next scopes:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.circles.read 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.circles.write 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.media.upload 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.stream.read 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.stream.write
```

My scope definition is:

```
private static final List<String> SCOPE = Arrays.asList(
       "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.circles.read", 
           "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.circles.write", 
           "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me", 
           "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.media.upload", 
           "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.stream.read", 
           "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.stream.write");
```

I'm a bit lost here , is there any way of debug this problem or know why is this access denied?

Comment: my request is the sample code of the quck start i only change the email, user and key

Comment: Can you post your code that makes the authorization request?

Comment: its exactly the same of the sample

Comment: To be more specific, can you include the new variables you set?

Comment: @user2753937 I am facing the same problem, did you ever solved this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things that you should check.

First, is the private key file that you downloaded from the [Google APIs Console](https://developers.google.com/console) in the correct path with your code?  This file is referenced by the following variable.  This needs to tell the OAuth client library where to find the file.

```
private static final String SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH =
"/path/to/<public_key_fingerprint>-privatekey.p12";
```

It is very important that you do not rename the file.

Second, does your scope list in your code match the list of scopes set in the Admin console?

The configuration in the Admin console for your Google Apps domain, and the scopes provided in the request must be *identical*.  Try adjusting the `SCOPE` variable **in your code** to be:

```
private static final List<String> SCOPE = Arrays.asList(
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.circles.read",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.circles.write",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.media.upload",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.stream.read",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.stream.write");
```

In general, it is best to only request the scopes that you will need, rather than all scopes available.

Third, make sure that the client ID you generated is the one listed on the Admin console entry that specifies the scopes permitted.

Comment: The scopes in your code need to match the scopes in the console.  It cannot be a subset of scopes in each code snippet, as needed.  It must be an exact match.

Comment: ok i will ask to the responsible for the cpanel the excat match and order of the scopes to match an i will give feedback here

thanks

Comment: Helo so this is the definition on the cpanel:
googleapis.com/auth/plus.circles.read 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.circles.write 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.media.upload 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.stream.read 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.stream.write

Comment: This is my Scope Definition:
private static final List<String> SCOPE = Arrays.asList(
     "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.circles.read", 
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.circles.write", 
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me", 
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.media.upload", 
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.stream.read", 
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.stream.write");

Comment: I edited my answer with an additional check.  Do you have the private key file in the correct place with the SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH variable?

Comment: yes  i am sure of that because if file path is incorrect the application returns me a file not found exception but in my case the error occurs after the authentication method

Comment: this is my path statement

private static final String SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH =
      "src/com/google/plus/samples/quickstart/domains/key.p12";

Comment: Did you rename the file to "key.p12"?  It is very important that you do not rename the file.

Comment: The key already was in the original name and the result was the same.
now i have downloaded a new key:  final String SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH =
      "src/com/google/plus/samples/quickstart/domains/05cab8e819cbd0a747b180c1f22fc93dba916b7b-privatekey.p12";